# in r how to think about visualization for some specific data

Tags: r

I have this dataset as below and want to apply a couple of visualization to it?

```
MC  AVGKM   TOTEVENT
US000328    51250.75    8
US000329    126793.50   8
US000331    86731.89    9
US000334    158354.33   6
US000335    85219.33    3
US000336    64360.57    7
US000342    101849.83   6
US000345    88532.00    6
US000348    100279.88   8
US000351    91005.00    4
US000355    152059.83   6
US000356    112415.67   6
US000358    122466.33   6
US000359    113440.83   6
US000364    120913.00   4
US000365    77460.57    7
US000366    161468.20   5
US000367    118975.29   7
US000368    99348.80    10
US000372    71232.67    6
US000375    44912.17    12
US000378    142300.38   8
US000380    78508.11    9
US000381    0.00    1
```

I was thinking of using barplot, but may be there are better other options.

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(above_df, id.var="MC")
df$MC=cut(df$MC,c(1:10))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(final_df, aes(x = MC, y = TOEVENT, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Can the visualization be different than I am trying?

Comment: if you have no idea what you'd like to achieve, it is going to be hard to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are interested in [Exploartory Data Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis). The "best" visualization is one that tells you something interesting about the data. There are no rules for what will work.  You should just try some different graphs and try to interpret them.  Can you learn anything about the data from them?

Here you have only two interesting variables - AVGKM and TOTEVENT. You can try to find out about each of them separately and about how they relate to each other.

Univariate - each variable separately

TOTEVENT seems to have only small integers as values,  so a barplot of that might help. Try   `hist(Dat$TOTEVENT)`

AVGKM seems to be a continuous variable so which a histogram could work,  I prefer to see a density plot.  `plot(density(Dat$AVGKM))`

Bivariate - both variables

The simplest view is just a scatterplot     `plot(Dat[,3:2], pch=20)` 
Many people like dotplots 
`dotchart(Dat$TOTEVENT[order(Dat$AVGKM)], Dat$AVGKM[order(Dat$AVGKM)])`

There are other possibilities, but you should try to explore the data for yourself. For each graph, ask what it tells you about the data. If you learn something from one graph, it might suggest a question about the data that will lead to another graph.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: thank you @G5W for suggestion and info.

Comment: For AVGKM, why would you prefer to see density? any specific reason?

Comment: Both histograms and density plots show the distribution of the data.  Histograms discretize the data and density plots are more continuous. But different discretizations can lead to substantially different visualizations. One must choose the boundaries carefully.  Density plots do not have this problem.  But try them both and see what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ggplot2" package as it is very flexible. It uses layer technique to add properties to charts. There are many resources available to learn and debug.

Thought Process: While making visuals, one should keep in mind what he/she is trying to answer. For e.g., if someone wants to see the correlation between 2 continuous variables than Scatter plot (point chart) could be useful.

Go through the below link of ggplot2 chart summary, it could be helpful in deciding among multiple charts
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf

Best Visualisation is a subjective question, which depends on domain knowledge of the problem.